# Best way to handle path segment in ASPNET CORE MVC

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an AWS ECS stack to deploy an ASPNet Core application, and the sample application you get works as expected if the application load balancer (ALB) is the root path:

> /

But, I would like to deploy several applications using path parameters:

> /aspnetapp
>
> /somotherapp

In my ALB, I set the path parameter as follows:

[image: AWS ECS ALB Path Parameter]

But, when I set the path, the application fails with 503.  To compensate, I have re-coded the Startup as follows:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        app.Map("/aspnetapp", HandleMapTest);

    }

    private static void HandleMapTest(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

This captures the path segment, but now scripts, images, and CSS styles fail to load.

What is the best way to configure the ASP Net Core app to run with a path parameter defined so everything is routed to /aspnetapp?

Comment: Load balancing/reverse proxy has to be transparent to the application. Read if you get request to http://example.com/app1/somecontroller/action/id you must redirect it to http://internalIP:portOfApp/somecontroller/action/id and make sure that the headers are correctly set/forwarded (`X-Forwarded-*` headers) and that your application also use th em (`UseForwardedHeaders` which happens implicitly when you use `UseIISIntegration. You shouldnt handle this in code. Dunno how you set up AWS for it though

Comment: Transparency is what I thought, the application should be able run the same anywhere.  But I think I am missing the reverse proxy knowledge.  In ECS ALB you can forward based on path and based on host-header.  But sounds like something in between is needed to make the application act like it is running on IP:PORT.

Comment: Kestrel is used in anycase to host the application. IIS (on Windows) or nginx (typical choice on Linux OS) are used as reverse proxy. Since Kestrel is not yet ready to act as internet facing server, it should only be used behind a reverse proxy (unlike Weblistener wich can also be hosted as internet facing server, but is limited to Windows). https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction describes on how to set nginx as reverse proxy for an ASP.NET Core application. When you use docker etc. you may need additional system for discovering the IPs/containers though